# How to deploy font which is not installed in other resource?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using a custom font which is installed on my PC but need to make it work over the web. Please share the possible ways.

Comment: You mean @font-face like this: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia

Comment: Or you could look into [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) and see if your font (or something close to it) is there.

Comment: ya thanks everyone i got it.. it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the link below which is hosted by google :)

https://www.google.com/fonts

Which you can use like below

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and styling your text like

```
.myAwesomeLookingTextEveryoneWillLaughAt { font-family: ‘Allura’, cursive; }
```

For more details, please visit the link.

Comment: So should I include how he can include the fonts in my answer? like the script src (which is yeah, available in the link but not just visible directly here).

Comment: Okay, thanks! :) Atleast I am learning here. I'll edit my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Define fonts in your css with font location :

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(location/font.ttf);
}
```

then use it as `p { font-family:myFont; }`

Comment: And how do you use that font on a P tag?

Comment: p { font-family:myFont; }

Comment: Include that in your answer then :P